# Call Java From Javascript (Birt)

Tags: java, javascript, class, package, birt

I want to call Java object from within javascript in my rptdesign file (which is under a report project), after i put the jar of my class in /Web-Inf/lib directory and the .class in Web-Inf/classes i tried something like this in the open event of the data set:

```
gsh = new Packages.de.vogella.birt.stocks.daomock.StockDaoMock(); 

stock = gsh.getStockValues();
```

`de.vogella.birt.stocks.daomock` is the name of a package located in a Java Project (ClassPackage) under `/src`

`StockDaoMock` is the name of the class.

`getStockValues()` is the method.

But I get this error:

```
cannot evaluate the script. data set script method fetch returned null.expected a boolean value.
```

What is wrong?

---

I tried to replace all the code in the fetch method by 
     "system.out.println("essai");
     return true;"
and still have this error 
     "Data Set script method "Fetch" returned null; expected a Boolean value."

Answer (score 2):

Enable logging to see the stack trace. [See the wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/BIRT/FAQ/Deployment#Q%3a_Can_I_use_Log4j_with_BIRT.3F).

Make sure the exception is logged (the example just logs the message) :-)

"[Quick and Dirty Logging](http://birtworld.blogspot.ch/2010/01/quick-and-dirty-logging.html)" might also help.

You might also have a classloader issue. [See this blog post](http://blog.pdark.de/2010/07/12/debugging-birt-how-do-i-enable-logging-for-osgiequinox/) for classloader options and how to debug bundle discovery by OSGi when using BIRT.

**[EDIT]** The error message means that you forgot `return true;` or `return false;` at the end of the `fetch` method.

Comment: The error is : 'cannot evaluate the script.
data set script method fetch returned null.expected a boolean value.'
Thank you anyway.

Comment: I use birt-report-designer-all-in-one-2_6_2

Comment: Thank you mister but there's a return true; at the end of my fetch method.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right method? If in doubt, add a couple of `println()`s and look into the console. Also make sure the method doesn't throw any exceptions? If in doubt, wrap it in a try-catch in JavaScript and print the exception to the console.

Answer (score -3):

The java runs on the server, and javascripts runs in the browser, so it is obvious you can't call Java from javascript directly.

There is a library called `DWR (Direct Web Remoting)`. It can expose Java method to Javascript methods. When you call the Javascript it makes a AJAX request, then `DWRServlet` handles it, executes your desired Java method, and returns the method result to the browser.

Comment: In birt, it's possible.

Comment: What is Birt? The BI by eclipse? It can't be, only some library like DWR is used.